# Installing MySQLdb

Tags: 12.04, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to install for mysql?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53937/what-to-install-for-mysql)

How do I install MySQLdb for my 12.04 LTS machine? I need it for a project I am working on. I see many many options in the Synaptic Package Manager, is there an easier way to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install MySQL on Ubuntu 12.04LTS, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

When that is done, run:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Once all is done, you need to secure, and configure your MySQL installation.