# How to run php web application in lamp server and how to do mysql connection

Tags: software-installation, php, mysql, lamp

I need your help.

1. I wanted to install php , mysql and apache server
2. How to run php web application in server?
3. How to connect php web application to mysql?

Comment: IMHO you would be better off asking this question in [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions).

Comment: but i want to execute my own code ..... HOW TO EXECUTE MY CODE MAN????

Answer (score 14):

[**This answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/281137/9598) provides details on LAMP and PHP Install. [**This answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/271987/9598) provides the details on "how to run php" on your web server.

In [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/53947/9598) you'll get the steps on how to install MySQL. But the details on how to connect php into mysql are too long and probably **off topic** right here. So I suggest you to first meet the requirements to properly run LAMP.

Additionally you may wish to have a look at [this post](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) on **howtoforge**, of which I place here the relevant things for your convenience:

> ## Installing LAMP On Ubuntu For Newbies
>
> In this guide I will show you how to install a LAMP system. LAMP stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP. The guide is intended to help
>   those who have very little knowlegde of using Linux.
>
> ### Install Apache
>
> To start off we will install Apache.
>
> 1. Open up the Terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal). (Ctrl+T also works)
> 2. Copy/Paste the following line of code into Terminal and then press enter:
>
>    sudo apt-get install apache2
> 3. The Terminal will then ask you for you're password, type it and then press enter.
>
> ### Testing Apache
>
> To make sure everything installed correctly we will now test Apache to ensure it is working properly.
>
> 1. Open up any web browser and then enter the following into the web address:
>
> `http://localhost/`
>
> You should see a folder entitled apache2-default/. Open it and you
>   will see a message saying "It works!" , congrats to you!
>
> ### Install PHP
>
> In this part we will install PHP 5.
>
> Step 1. Again open up the Terminal (Applications > Accessories >
>   Terminal). Step 2. Copy/Paste the following line into Terminal and
>   press enter:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
> ```
>
> Step 3. In order for PHP to work and be compatible with Apache we must
>   restart it. Type the following code in Terminal to do this:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
> ```
>
> Test PHP
>   -- To ensure there are no issues with PHP let's give it a quick test run.
>
> Step 1. In the terminal copy/paste the following line: *updated*
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /var/www/html/testphp.php
> ```
>
> This will open up a file called phptest.php.
>
> Step 2. Copy/Paste this line into the phptest file:
>
> ```
> <?php phpinfo(); ?>
> ```
>
> Step 3. Save and close the file.
>
> Step 4. Now open you're web browser and type the following into the
>   web address:
>
> ```
> http://localhost/testphp.php
> ```
>
> The page should look like this:
>
> [image]

Good luck!

Comment: I just get a blank page when I do this. I can run a .html file but the php files just turn up blank. If I type in just 'localhost' I get this: post_title; ?>

>

'postThumb', 'alt' => ''.get_the_title().'', 'title' => ''.get_the_title().'')); ?> 'postThumb alignleft', 'alt' => ''.get_the_title().'', 'title' => ''.get_the_title().'')); ?> What do?

Comment: Does it occur when you try to reach http://localhost/ or the http://localhost/testphp.php ?

Comment: i'm typing just 'localhost' into the internet browser search bar.

Comment: The results you are receiving like ".get_the_title()." etc, seems to be related to a CMS like Wordpress, Joomla, etc. Please verify your current www folder has an index.php and check its contents. If you need further details on this it will be great if you open your own question to receive the proper help. This question seems to be solved for now. In addition, there is a http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ site in which you can find help for WP CMS, but if it is related to a different one you should find the proper forum to request for help as this is an Ubuntu related support place.

Comment: But, if you have these issues by running the code provided in the answer then please make sure you have already installed all the recommended software in order to get the right results. Remember that you need PHP5 installed to have Apache process PHP files, you need to install the PHP module for Apache:

    sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Comment: I verified installation of php5 by typing 'which php5' into the terminal & I get a directory, indicating it's been installed.I did try something new & get a the expected result you mention in your answer post.There's a folder in my www folder called 'html' & when I put the 'testphp.php' file into there & type 'localhost/testphp.php' into the search bar it loads the expected page. From you description though it seems that the browser should be looking in the www folder, is this correct? In any case,how would I change this directory? There is a index.php file in both folders, still blank screen.

Comment: Please check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/76961/9598 and inform if you succeed.